# Upgrade newtonsoft.json breaks DNN 9.1 persona bar

Tags: json.net, dotnetnuke, sendgrid, dotnetnuke-9

I'm trying to integrate SendGrid into my app and it has a dependency on newtonsoft.json.9.0.1.  DNN9 ships with newtonsoft.json.7.0.0.  However, if I add the binding redirect bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.1" the site loads, but the persona bar is broken.

I'm completely blocked on this.  How do I upgrade newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Try add to webconfig code:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```